# Find directory, if match then don't recurse

Tags: find, osx

On my Mac, I screwed up my android SDK installation. I was looking to clean it out by finding all references to "android".

The issue is, when I run the command `find / -name "*android*"` I get quite an extensive list.

Instead of this list:

```
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-23
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-24
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-25
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-26
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-19
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-28
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms/android-N
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/system-images/android-23
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/system-images/android-19
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/system-images/android-N
...
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-15
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-16
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-18
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-20
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-21
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-19
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-10
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework/Versions/5.1.2-1/lib/mandroid/platforms/android-17
```

I would like to get:

```
/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk
/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework
```

It doesn't search the subdirectories if the directory matches.

Comment: @Goro how? I need it to search the subdirs but only if it doesn't match

Comment: @Goro I thought the question outlined it fairly clearly, I want the result to, no matter how deep, stop searching the subdirectories of paths that match `*android*`

Comment: eg: `/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk/platforms` wouldn't be searched because `/usr/local/var/lib/android-sdk` already matches `*android*`

Comment: If you want to find all the files except the ones that have `*android*` in it, then your command should be `find / ! -name "*android*"`

Comment: @Goro No, I *want* to find folders that match `*android*`, but I don't want to see the *child* folders of these folders

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need directories:

```
find . -type d -iname '*android*' -a \( -prune  \)
```

Coments on code:

```
.             # Present directory
-type d       # Only directories
-iname        # Instead of `-name` to also match "Android" (ignore case).
'*android*'   # Pattern of name to search
-a            # Force the execution of next option on matching names.
              # probably redundant as all options are evaluated with an
              # implicit and in find
              # but: makes the intent explicitly clear.
\( -prune  \) # Remove the whole directory from further examination.
              # braces also optional (as it is only one command).
```

Simplified:

```
find . -type d -iname '*android*' -prune
```

---

If you also want files:

```
find . -iname '*android*' -a \( -prune  \)
```

Caveat: this will report all files found and then directories. It is not clear if if a file named "android" is found that the corresponding directory should be avoided.